# Use "ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()" to select audio files

Tags: android

I want to use ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument() to have the user pick a file from local storage, and I want to limit the choices to audio files.

To do this I'm passing "audio/*" as the Mime type, but it doesn't work. The file picker that appears doesn't give me access to any files (there are audio files such as MP3 files present on my device).

If I pass "*/*" then I can see and select the audio files, but also any other kind of file.

What is the correct way to limit the choice to audio files?

Comment: What does "The file picker that appears doesn't give me access to any files" mean? You see valid mp3 files in the file picker but it doesn't let you select them? It might be helpful to include a screenshot of what you are seeing and the code you are using with `OpenDocument`

Comment: Well, here's the deal. The files I uploaded to my phone through Android Studio didn't appear until I rebooted my phone. I'm guessing there's some bug in Android where it caches the directory contents and doesn't check for new files.